# Organizing web parts on sharepoint.

Tags: page-layout

I am new to sharepoint and I am designing a dashboard. I need to implement a custom "layout" (not sure if this is the correct term) for the dashboard page.   I am not entirely sure on how to do this and would appreciate any pointers to the resources for doing this.

[image: Example Wireframe]

This is the layout I would like to achieve. With the three list views on the right that align with three web charts, another list on the bottom underneath the charts. and finally two more lists on the left followed by an RSS feed and twitter.

I appreciate any input here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every HTML/ASP.NET rules are valid in web part user interface development. So you can make your design/layout in aspx designer with tables or divs and go-on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your charts and items are web parts you could use a web part page that provides four web part zones to be each of the columns you show and drop the web parts into the appropriate columns.